# Cassandra CQL3 Import CSV

Tags: cassandra

*Background:*

I have created a Schema called AvailableDomains (simple strategy, 1 node).

In that keyspace I have created 1 table/ column family called domains with columns (id, urn, timestamp, flag). All of type text except timestamp is type timestamp.

I startup cassandra,

launch cqlsh -3,

use AvailableDomains,

and then issue the following command to pull in a csv:

```
COPY domains (id, urn, timestamp, flag) from 'test.csv' where HEADER= TRUE;
```

I get an error saying: *Improper COPY command*

**Question:
What am I doing wrong?**

*Details:*

*CSV-*

```
id,url,timestamp,flag
1,google.com,1375891081,1
2,facebook.com,1375891081,1
3,youtube.com,1375891081,1
4,yahoo.com,1375891081,1
5,baidu.com,1375891081,1
6,wikipedia.org,1375891081,1
7,amazon.com,1375891081,1
8,qq.com,1375891081,1
9,live.com,1375891081,1
10,linkedin.com,1375891081,1
```

*Location* of csv is in cassandra/bin (same dir where cqlsh is located).

*OS:* Centos 6.4 64bit

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This fixed me up for CQL 3:

```
COPY domains FROM 'test.csv' WITH HEADER = true ;
```

The reason I am using Header = True is the first line of my CSV has the column names. Hope this helps someone else out there.

Comment: Using double quotes around the file name like: "test.csv" will give this error as well. use single quotes instead like: 'test.csv'

Comment: also leaving out the space between "HEADER=true" will give the same error