# how can I add csv to cassandra db?

Tags: cassandra

I know it can be done in traditional way, but if I were to use Cassandra DB, is there a easy/quick and agaile way to add csv to the DB as a set of key-value pairs ?

Ability to add a time-series data coming via CSV file is my prime requirement. I am ok to switch to any other database such as mongodb, rike, if it is conviniently doable there..

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18109499/cassandra-cql3-import-csv

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit 2** Dec 02, 2017
Please use port 9042. Cassandra access has changed to CQL with default port as 9042, 9160 was default port for Thrift.

**Edit 1**
There is a better way to do this without any coding. Look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18110080/298455

However, if you want to pre-process or something custom you may want to so it yourself. here is a lengthy method:

---

1. Create a column family.

   ```
   cqlsh> create keyspace mykeyspace 
   with strategy_class = 'SimpleStrategy' 
   and strategy_options:replication_factor = 1;

   cqlsh> use mykeyspace;

   cqlsh:mykeyspace> create table stackoverflow_question 
   (id text primary key, name text, class text);
   ```

   Assuming your CSV is like this:

   ```
   $ cat data.csv 
   id,name,class
   1,hello,10
   2,world,20
   ```
2. Write a simple Python code to read off of the file and dump into your CF. Something like this:

   ```py
   import csv 
   from pycassa.pool import ConnectionPool
   from pycassa.columnfamily import ColumnFamily

   pool = ConnectionPool('mykeyspace', ['localhost:9160'])
   cf = ColumnFamily(pool, "stackoverflow_question")

   with open('data.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
     for row in reader:
       print str(row)
       key = row['id']
       del row['id']
       cf.insert(key, row)

   pool.dispose()
   ```
3. Execute this:

   ```
   $ python loadcsv.py 
   {'class': '10', 'id': '1', 'name': 'hello'}
   {'class': '20', 'id': '2', 'name': 'world'}
   ```
4. Look the data:

   ```
   cqlsh:mykeyspace> select * from stackoverflow_question;
    id | class | name
   ----+-------+-------
     2 |    20 | world
     1 |    10 | hello
   ```
5. See also:

   a. Beware of [DictReader](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)
   b. Look at [Pycassa](http://pycassa.github.io/pycassa/tutorial.html)
   c. Google for existing CSV loader to Cassandra. I guess there are.
   d. There may be a simpler way using CQL driver, I do not know.
   e. Use appropriate data type. I just wrapped them all into text. Not good.

HTH

---

I did not see the time-series requirement. Here is how you do for time series.

1. This is your data

   ```
   $ cat data.csv
   id,1383799600,1383799601,1383799605,1383799621,1383799714
   1,sensor-on,sensor-ready,flow-out,flow-interrupt,sensor-killAll
   ```
2. Create traditional wide row. (CQL suggests not to use [COMPACT STORAGE](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/does-cql-support-dynamic-columns-wide-rows), but this is just to get you going quickly.)

   ```
   cqlsh:mykeyspace> create table timeseries 
   (id text, timestamp text, data text, primary key (id, timestamp)) 
   with compact storage;
   ```
3. This the altered code:

   ```py
   import csv
   from pycassa.pool import ConnectionPool
   from pycassa.columnfamily import ColumnFamily

   pool = ConnectionPool('mykeyspace', ['localhost:9160'])
   cf = ColumnFamily(pool, "timeseries")

   with open('data.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
     for row in reader:
       print str(row)
       key = row['id']
       del row['id']
       for (timestamp, data) in row.iteritems():
         cf.insert(key, {timestamp: data})

   pool.dispose()
   ```
4. This is your timeseries

   ```
   cqlsh:mykeyspace> select * from timeseries;
    id | timestamp  | data
   ----+------------+----------------
     1 | 1383799600 |      sensor-on
     1 | 1383799601 |   sensor-ready
     1 | 1383799605 |       flow-out
     1 | 1383799621 | flow-interrupt
     1 | 1383799714 | sensor-killAll
   ```

Comment: How do you know that Cassandra use port 9160 ? because I get the following error : `An attempt was made to connect to each of the servers twice, but none of the attempts succeeded. The last failure was TTransportException: Could not connect to localhost:9160`

Answer (score 5):

Let's say your CSV looks like

```
'P38-Lightning', 'Lockheed', 1937, '.7'
```

1. `cqlsh` to your DB
2. And..

   ```
   CREATE TABLE airplanes (
    name text PRIMARY KEY,
    manufacturer ascii,
    year int,
    mach float
   );
   ```
3. then...

   ```
   COPY airplanes (name, manufacturer, year, mach) FROM '/classpath/temp.csv';
   ```

Refer: http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/references/cql/COPY

Answer (score 4):

Do Backup

```
./cqlsh -e"copy <keyspace>.<table> to '../data/table.csv';"
```

Use backup

```
./cqlsh -e"copy <keyspace>.<table> from '../data/table.csv';"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is now an open-source program for bulk-loading data (local or remote) into Cassandra from *multiple* files (CSVs or JSONs) called **DataStax Bulk Loader** (see [docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/1.9.0/dsbulkAbout.html), [source](https://github.com/datastax/dsbulk), [examples](https://github.com/datastax/dsbulk#load-examples)):

```
dsbulk load -url ~/my_data_folder -k keyspace1 -t table1 -header true
```